# how to convert string representation of regular expression to automaton with java?

Tags: java, regex

is there any way to convert the string representation of a regular expression into automaton with java?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
boolean b = m.matches();
```

See details at http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html